# Surrounding line with quotes using sed in WSL2 Ubuntu not working as expected

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing, sed, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The command: `sed -e 's/.*/\"&\",/'`

I tested the regex at https://sed.js.org/ and it worked correctly, so if I had input like this:

```
George Washington, 1789-1797
John Adams, 1797-1801
Thomas Jefferson, 1801-1809
```

I get output like this according to the website:

```
"George Washington, 1789-1797",
"John Adams, 1797-1801",
"Thomas Jefferson, 1801-1809",
```

But when I run the command in WSL2 Ubuntu, I get output like this:

```
",eorge Washington, 1789-1797
",ohn Adams, 1797-1801
",homas Jefferson, 1801-1809
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: That's likely nothing to do with sed being on WSL2 - it's because your input file has Windows line endings (CRLF instead of plain LF)

Comment: Hello, what happens if you remove the `,` comma from the replacement?

Comment: You have DOS line endings, see [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, that was it. I used dos2unix to convert the line endings and then the sed command worked as expected.

Comment: @ed-morton thanks!